# Using json_encode with PHP to add a class in another div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I'm using WordPress to `get_categories` into a variable and then trying to get the category name from the `get_categories` array to then pass that into a jQuery variable to have it check against another conditional in jQuery.

So far, I'm able to get the data from `get_categories` correctly and then use `json_encode` to parse that array into a json format.

But what I'm getting hung up on is I just want the `name` that is coming from the `get_categories` array from WordPress and then pass that into jQuery to run the conditional.

I'm not sure of the proper way to get that formatted correctly so that jQuery can interpret that without getting all cranky about it.

Here's what I have so far:

**Code:**

```
  <?php $test = get_categories('taxonomy=stuff&type=item'); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
              var $things = <?php echo json_encode($test); ?>
              $(".this-div").each(function() {
                var $item = $(this).attr("title");
                if ($things.indexOf($item) > -1) {
                  $(this).addClass('current');
                }
              });
            });
            </script>
```

I've tried `$test[0]->name` but that's only going to return one of the values and not all of them.
So, I'm not sure if I'm going about this correctly or if there is a better way possibly.

Comment: Not sure if php has a built in map function, but conceptually you'd loop through the $test element and build another array from all the names, and that's what you would echo to the $things

Comment: Yeah, I was trying out a `foreach` loop as well, but that was yielding some zany results. Plus all efforts was leading me down the `json_encode` path, which appears that it should work, but I feel that I'm missing something...

Comment: You will need json_encode at the end for the resulting array to turn it into the structure that javascript will be able to parse into an array to store in $things, but you have to create the array of names you give it first.

Comment: Otherwise you might could potentially leave it like this, and then your `if()` conditional would change to something possibly like `if ($things.find(function(element){ return element.name === $item; }))`  Ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: That was the other thing I wasn't sure about which was where would I put the `foreach` loop in the order of operations to store those names into a variable to be pulled out with jQuery.

Comment: You'd do the foreach inside a <? ?> block before the line that does the json_encode (you could actually do this in side the same block where the $test is created at the top).  You'd build the secondary array there, and then you'd use that secondary array in the json_encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with this:

```
<?php 
$test = get_categories('taxonomy=item&type=things');
$names = array_column($test, 'name'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $things = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
  console.log($things);
  $(".element").each(function() {
    var $state = $(this).attr("title");
    if ($things.indexOf($state) > -1) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

From here: [Using jQuery script with WordPress foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52932977/using-jquery-script-with-wordpress-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I use word press, but if `get_categories()` just returns a JSON string you could do something like this:

```
<p class="categories"><?php echo get_categories('taxonomy=stuff&type=item')></p>
<script>
    let categories = JSON.parse($('.categories').text());
    $(".this-div").each(function() {
      let $div = $(this);
      if (categories.includes($div.attr("title")) {
        $div.addClass('current');
      }
  });
</script>
```

The `hp` part in `php` means `Hypertext Preprocessor`, as in it preprocesses the hypertext. It doesn't work within a script. However, you can use it to write data to an element in the hypertext and then access that from a script.
As long as you put the hypertext before the script in the document, you shouldn't have to wait for the entire document to load. <strike>`$(document).ready()`</strike>

Also, if you're going to use `$(this)` multiple times, it's recommended that you save it as a variable to save redundant jquery function calls. I find future self appreciates if you name it something more descriptive than `$this`.

Oh yeah, and [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). It's a cleaner way of saying `.index() > -1`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, `get_categories` doesn't come back as json, so that's why it needs to be encoded or parsed out in some way. But this does help tidy up the jQuery part of it.