# Using jQuery script with WordPress foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, foreach

Currently, I have this script:

```
<?php $test = get_categories('taxonomy=item&type=things');?>

    <?php foreach($test as $stuff) : ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
          var $things = <?php echo json_encode($stuff->name); ?>;
          console.log($things);
          $(".element").each(function() {
            var $state = $(this).attr("title");
            if ($things.indexOf($state) > -1) {
              $(this).addClass('current');
            }
          });
        });
        </script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Which is working, but I'm not sure how to get it out of the `foreach` loop so that it doesn't keep repeating the jQuery script over and over again.

Overall, I'm trying to get the values out from the `get_categories` via WordPress, but then pass the `name` value from the array and then check that within jQuery to add a class to specific elements within a div.

I know I'm probably going about the wrong way, so I'm completely open to suggestion if anyone knows a better, cleaner way of approaching this.

Comment: If you want it to be executed once only then use a flag (`$has_executed = false`) which can be toggled.

Comment: Where would that go specifically? In the `foreach` loop or somewhere else?

Comment: I think you're talking about not repeatedly outputting the JS code into the page, rather than not repeatedly executing it? Put the existing JS stuff into a JS function which you place elsewhere, outside the loop. Make it accept a single argument as input to the function. Then in the script block within the loop, the only JS you need is a call to this function, where you pass $things as the argument. Then you've got the function written once, but called many times. That's what functions are for, after all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use array_column() to get all the names. Not tested code below

```
<?php 
$test = get_categories('taxonomy=item&type=things');
$names = array_column($test, 'name'); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $things = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
  console.log($things);
  $(".element").each(function() {
    var $state = $(this).attr("title");
    if ($things.indexOf($state) > -1) {
      $(this).addClass('current');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Actually this works out as intended, thanks! I'll keep messing with it cause I might have more data that might come back from that eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I like to separate PHP from JS as much as possible, and prevent multiple iterations. So I handle `$names` in PHP, then `json_encode` it for the JS portion to evaluate. Code below (not tested).

```
<?php
  $test = get_categories('taxonomy=item&type=things');

  foreach ($test as $stuff) {
    $names[] = $stuff->name;
  }
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $things = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;
    console.log($things);
    $(".element").each(function() {
      var $state = $(this).attr("title");
      if ($things.indexOf($state) > -1) {
        $(this).addClass('current');
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, yeah. This is also what I was wondering about. A way to loop through the array, but have it stored in a variable. This helps, thanks!